# A simple modular reconstruction conundrum on CRT

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Assume we have two primes $r$ and $s$.

Assume that we have $a =N\bmod r$ and $b=N\bmod s$, then can we find $N\bmod rs$ using CRT?

All explanations I have found say that if we have $rs>N$, then we can find $N$.

My query is what happens if $rs<N$ and $rst>N$ can we still find $N\bmod rs$, $N\bmod st$, $N\bmod tr$? Assume $N\bmod t$ is known at a third prime $t$ and assume $N\bmod r$ and $N\bmod s$ also is known $r$ and $s$ prime

CRT guarantees $N=N\bmod rst$.

That is I want $N$ to be found and without using $N$ find $N\bmod rs$, $N\bmod st$, $N\bmod tr$ so that the $N$ we found agrees with find $N\bmod rs$, $N\bmod st$, $N\bmod tr$ at moduli $rs,st,tr$ respectively

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the solution goes this way: find with the *Extended Euclidean algorithm* coefficients $u$  and $v$ such that
$$ur+vs=1,\quad \lvert u\rvert < s,\enspace \lvert v\rvert < r.$$
The solutions are
$$N\equiv bru+avs\mod rs.$$
Thus, if you have  $N>rs$, you only have to reduce $N$ modulo $rs$.

Comment: you mean $|u|<r$?

Comment: No, I mean $\lvert v\rvert<r$. Thank you for pointing the typo!

Comment: updated query to be more clear

Comment: You now have $3$ primes, or $3$ products of primes, but only $2$ congruences. So…?

Comment: updated clearer?

Comment: Yes: you want to solve a system of $3$ congurences.  The method I recall  works if you first solve a pair of congruences, obtaib a solution mod $rs$, and combine this congruence with the last one. In other words, you solve in pairs. Then you reduce the value found modulo $rst$ if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I want to again make it clear what I want. I dont see it though as a proof. See **(1.)** I get $N\bmod rst$ from which I know $N$ (Good I got $N$) **(2.)** Without $N$ I should be able to get $a=N \bmod rs$, $b=N \bmod st$, $c= N \bmod tr$ and **(3.)** from 1) I got $N$ and now if I apply $N \bmod rs$, $N \bmod st$, $N \bmod tr$ each should be in agreement with $a,b,c$ respectively. correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What I don't see is how you get $N\bmod rs$, &c. without having $N\bmod rst$.

Comment: My point is we should be able to get $c$ from $N\bmod r$ and $N\bmod s$. Now $c$ should agree with $N\bmod rs$ (say you obtained $N$ from first getting $N\bmod tr$ and getting $N\bmod rst$ from $N\bmod tr$ and $N\bmod s$ this is what I mean (no matter what order you choose to get $N$, the obtained $N$ is unique and obtained intermediate moduli also are unique and they agree with $N$ modulo the moduli we choose (say we have $100$ diff primes instead of $3$ we have many ways to get N but every intermediate moduli constructed by CRT should agree with final $N$ mod intermediate product of primes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31282/discussion-between-bernard-and-arul).

Comment: I am still on chat

Comment: @Arul: I'm back.

Comment: Is there a way to formally prove  M mod r1r76r87r99 = N mod r1r76r87r99 in the chat?

Comment: posted another problem in chat

Comment: @Arul: I've answered in chat.

Comment: If you wish you can post for this problem here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223379/a-bounded-residue-problem